# Can a function $f$ such that $f(x) < 0$, $f'(x) < 0$ and $f''(x) > 0$ for all $x$ exist?

Tags: calculus

Question:
Is the following statement true or false:

These exists a function $f$ such that $f(x) < 0$, $f'(x) < 0$ and $f''(x) > 0$ for all $x$.

My first thought was the statement is false because  $f''(x) > 0$ is increasing for all $x$ and therefore at some point $f'(x)$ will
be positive. However, it might be the case that:

$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } f'(x) = K$ where $K < 0$. That is, $f'(x)$ has a limit less than $0$.

Hence, I do not know.

Comment: I assume that the function is $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. $f''(x) > 0$ for all $x$ means that the function is convex $\Rightarrow$ $f$ lies above a tangent line drawn at any point $x_0$. Since $f'(x_0) < 0$, this line tends to $+\infty$ when $x \to -\infty$.

Comment: For all $x$ you mean $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$? If you mean for all $x$ in its domain, for example a bounded interval, it is not difficult to show examples.

Comment: Did you leave out some detail? Was it perhaps "for all $x > 0$" rather than just "for all $x$"?

Answer (score 1):

Let $c=f'(x_0)<0$.
Then for $x<0$, we have $\frac{f'(0)-f'(x)}{0-x}=f''(\xi)>0$ for some $\xi$. Hence $f'(x)<c$ for $x<0$.
Next, and again for $x<0$, we have $\frac{f(0)-f(x)}{0-x}=f'(\eta)$ for some $\eta<0$. By the above,
$$f(x)>f(0)+cx \quad \text{for }x<0.$$
As $x_0:=-\frac{f(0)}{c}$ is negative, we arrive at $f(x_0)>0$.

Comment: If I understand what you are saying the answer to the original question is false. Do I have that right?

Answer (score 0):

$f''(x) > 0$ for all x, therefore $f'(x)$ is increasing, therefore $f'(x) < f'(0)$ for all x < 0, therefore $f(x) > f(0) + xf'(0)$ for all $x < 0$, therefore $f(x) > 0$ for $x < f(0) / f'(0)$.

What's slightly interesting is finding an example if the last condition is $f''(x) < 0 for all x.